# How to check for Duplicates in Security Rules Arrays?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

### Problem

I want to ensure that an array field in my Cloud Firestore documents does not contain any duplicate entries, however, I could not find any [methods in the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.List) that would allow me to check this easily.

### Code

I came up with a possible solution that ensures that a list can only contain `a` and `b` and not have duplicate entries.

```js
function containsNoDuplicates(array) {
  return array is list
         && array.size() <= 2
         && array.hasOnly(['a', 'b'])
         && (
              array.size() <= 1
              || (array.size() == 2 && array.hasAll(['a', 'b']))
            )
         ;
}
```

This is equivalent to the following function:

```js
function containsNoDuplicates(array) {
  return array == []
         || array == ['a']           
         || array == ['b']
         || array == ['a', 'b']
         || array == ['b', 'a']
         ;
}
```

#### Problem with these solutions

As you might be able to tell, this **scales horribly**. If I want to allow only a specific set of say a dozen elements, how would I go about that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is actually an undocumented language feature in security rules that allows you to convert a list to a new "set" type object that is guaranteed to have no duplicates.  Any dups in the list will be collapsed in the set.  This means that all you have to do is compare the size of the original list to the size of the set to find out if there are dups:

```
function containsNoDuplicates(array) {
  return array.toSet().size() == array.size();
}
```

Comment: Amazing! Is this similar to `writeFields`, meaning that it might not be supported in the future, or is it simply missing from the documentation?

Comment: The language feature is just so new that the docs team hasn't caught up.  It will be fully supported going forward, so you can count on it.  (I wouldn't have given the answer otherwise! :-)